# Engine sputters when accelerating and idle

Tags: fuel-system, troubleshooting, bmw, fuel-injection

I have a 1995 BMW 525i, when accelerating car seems to sputter, but as you get up to speed and cruise its fine.

I think it might be the fuel injectors. Where should I start?

Comment: not really an answer just advice: 1) you asked for like 3 completely different things in one post.  Next time break it up so people can see a focused question and can follow that with a focused answer. 2) a/c does what? 3) You bought a bimmer.  Learn to take off the fan shroud and learn to love it. On these cars just about every job involves taking out the fan and the shroud.  It seems annoying at first, but after few times you should be able to remove the fan in under 5 minutes.  If you need a tool to hold the fan, you can easily fabricate one with stock metal from home depot or buy one($36)

Comment: Welcome to the site! I edited your question, removing two of the three you asked. Both the questions I removed are welcome here but should be posted as separate questions. I changed the wording a little, but did not intend to change the meaning of your question about sputtering. If you would like to change what I did simply click on the word edit below the tags and edit away.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall right, those vehicles have a lot of vacuum hoses. Vacuum is only really utilized during idle, hence the disappearance of your problem. The sputtering is likely related to a dying vehicle, and as you accelerate it is able to keep running. Open your hood, and start looking at all the rubber hoses; compress them with your hand slightly and you can feel the ones that are in the process of dry rotting.